# Defining a custom template with a custom URLin wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am try to make a wordpress template just like author.php for my project. Its url should be like

```
/location/location-name
```

The filename should be `location.php` and it will GET values of location-name for the above url.

I am looking this in wp-routes but no success so far.

I can also do this through .htaccess but i want to make location.php file for this work.

```
    add_action( 'init', 'location_template_init' );
function location_template_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'location.php?location_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

I am not sure about this code.

Comment: Why don't you use wordpress custom post types and template for that? that will do what you need.

Comment: If i use custom post type the my url will not be like /location/{{location-name}}

Comment: http://www.fellbrewery.co.uk/beer/yolo/ look here how I used it ( this is a one of site I developed for a customer ) In this case the url is sitename/beer/{beer-name}. So, you can get your URL pattern using custom post types. If you need I can share code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use the WP default template rule.

1: Suppose your custom post type slug : location

2: Then your file name will be : `archive-location.php`

3: Now it will listed all the post of this Custom post type by URL :

```
http://www.example.com/location
```

4:Your post single URL will be :

```
http://www.example.com/location/#locationame#
```

Comment: In my project "locations" are just like "author". They can post and edit them. So custom post type will not work.